# Определить предикат

Tags: синтаксис

> ***Жаль***, что вы уже уходите.

Если я определила тип придаточного предложения правильно, это изъяснительное. Скажите, пожалуйста, неужели "жаль" предикат в главном предложении?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, а жаль ― предикат. Жаль ― слово категории состояния в роли сказуемого в безличном предложении, имеет значение эмоционального состояния.  Эмоции могут также выражать предикативные наречия (приятно, досадно), их также относят к словам категории состояния.

Эти слова могут  иметь при себе связку в прошедшем времени ― было жаль.

Comment: игнорируйте мой последний вопрос, всё поняла! muchas gracias, eres un sol =)